# Relationship with attribute laravel 8

Tags: laravel, database, eloquent, laravel-8, eloquent-relationship

I want make relationship with attribute but i dont understand how to do that with laravel ORM Eloquent, can somebody help me? Thanks in advance

[image: relational diagram image]

Comment: using laravel you cant define a single relation for the 3 entities. What you can do is declare a ManyToMany relation between `Mahasiswa` and `Role` as `roles()` and another ManyToMany relation between `Mahasiswa` and `Team` as `teams()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, you want to have a many-to-many relationship between your `Mahasiswa` and `Team`. Basically, it means that you have many teams, and each teams has its own members, so does members, each member can have teams. So you will need an intermediate/a pivot table between those two, for ex. `mahasiswa_team`. Then, inside `mahasiswa_team` table, you could add the `role` column to define each member's role.

For many-to-many relationship inside Laravel 8, you can see the documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations).

If many-to-many relationship is not correct, then my last guess is you want the one-to-many relationship between `Team` and `Mahasiswa`. In that case, you want to move your `role` column to the `Mahasiswa` table. For one-to-many relationship, you can see the documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many).